# Multiple Column Pivot in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a table where there are multiple rows that I need pivoted into columns.  So the pivot is the perfect solution for this, and works well when all I need is one field.  I am needing to return several fields based upon the pivot.  Here is the pseudo code with specifics stripped out:

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    field1, 
    field2, 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field2)) RowID
  FROM tblname
  ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
  (
  MAX(field2)
  FOR RowID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
  ) AS PivotTable;
```

The above syntax works brilliantly, but what do I do when I need to get additional information found in field3, field4....?

Comment: Exactly what do you need to have?

Comment: Tried it, working well for me(3rd approach in the blog). http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65786/query-pivot-multiple-columns-variable-number-of-rows

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rewrite using MAX(CASE...) and GROUP BY:

```
select 
  field1
, [1] = max(case when RowID = 1 then field2 end)
, [2] = max(case when RowID = 2 then field2 end)
, [3] = max(case when RowID = 3 then field2 end)
, [4] = max(case when RowID = 4 then field2 end)
from (
  select 
    field1
  , field2
  , RowID = row_number() over (partition by field1 order by field2)
  from tblname
  ) SourceTable
group by 
  field1
```

From there you can add in field3, field4, etc.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using CASe statements in a CTE to populate this derived table, which I joined with additional criteria.

Here is the CTE:

Comment: With cteSec as (
 SELECT
   vSec.ID,
   --Secretary 1 -------------------------
   MAX(
  CASE vSec.RowID
    WHEN 1 THEN vSec.field1
    ELSE ''
  END
   ) [SEC_OfficePhone1],
   MAX(
  CASE vSec.RowID
    WHEN 1 THEN vSec.field2
    ELSE ''
  END
   ) [SEC_OfficeFax1],   
 FROM
   (
   --THIS WILL BE THE INNER QUERY (it assigns rows to secretaries)
   SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
  field1, field2, ID
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vs.ID ORDER BY vs.ID2)) RowID
   FROM tblname vs
   ORDER BY vs.ID, ID2
   ) vSec
 GROUP BY 
   vSec.ID 
)

Comment: So through this method I have hardcoded the number of columns I am expecting.  I generally would prefer to do this dynamically, as its bound to change.  But as a company, we are focusing on overhead reduction, so I do not see the need for more than four secretaries per boss...

I am giving you the credit because your post led me down the road to writing the 20 case statements.  This works like a charm with a sub-second response.

Comment: Glad to be of help. A text editor with column mode/rectangular edit really helps with writing the repetitive CASE statements. UltraEdit and Emacs come to mind.

For a dynamic number of columns, you would need to use dynamic SQL. Here's the best place to read about that: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Also, I'm not sure the TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY trick still works reliably after SQL2K. The ROW_NUMBER() function will force the results into that order anyhow.

Comment: This is better than the Pivot/Unpivot approach I used to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241450/sql-pivot-with-multiple-columns  Your way is easier to read/code and I believe it runs faster.

Answer (score 3):

The trick to doing multiple pivots over a row_number is to modify that row number sequence to store both the sequence and the field number.  Here's an example that does what you want with multiple PIVOT statements.

```
-- populate some test data
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp') is not null drop table #tmp
create table #tmp (
    ID int identity(1,1) not null,
    MainField varchar(100),
    ThatField int,
    ThatOtherField datetime
)

insert into #tmp (MainField, ThatField, ThatOtherField)
select 'A', 10, '1/1/2000' union all
select 'A', 20, '2/1/2000' union all
select 'A', 30, '3/1/2000' union all
select 'B', 10, '1/1/2001' union all
select 'B', 20, '2/1/2001' union all
select 'B', 30, '3/1/2001' union all
select 'B', 40, '4/1/2001' union all
select 'C', 10, '1/1/2002' union all
select 'D', 10, '1/1/2000' union all
select 'D', 20, '2/1/2000' --union all

-- pivot over multiple columns using the 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 sequence trick
select
    MainField,
    max([1.1]) as ThatField1,
    max([1.2]) as ThatOtherField1,
    max([2.1]) as ThatField2,
    max([2.2]) as ThatOtherField2,
    max([3.1]) as ThatField3,
    max([3.2]) as ThatOtherField3,
    max([4.1]) as ThatField4,
    max([4.2]) as ThatOtherField4
from
    (
        select x.*,
            cast(row_number() over (partition by MainField order by ThatField) as varchar(2)) + '.1' as ThatFieldSequence,
            cast(row_number() over (partition by MainField order by ThatField) as varchar(2)) + '.2' as ThatOtherFieldSequence
        from #tmp x
    ) a
    pivot (
        max(ThatField) for ThatFieldSequence in ([1.1], [2.1], [3.1], [4.1])
    ) p1
    pivot (
        max(ThatOtherField) for ThatOtherFieldSequence in ([1.2], [2.2], [3.2], [4.2])
    ) p2
group by
    MainField
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if you are using MS SQL Server, but if you are... You may want to take a look at the CROSS APPLY functionality of the engine. Basically it will allow you to apply the results of a table-valued UDF to a result set. This would require you to put your pivot query into a table-valued result set.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx

Answer (score 1):

wrap your sql statement with something like:

```
select a.segment, sum(field2), sum(field3) 
from (original select with case arguments) a
group by a.segment
```

It should collapse your results into one row, grouped on field1.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pivot on multiple columns, but you need to be careful about reusing the pivot column across multiple pivots.  Here is a good blog post on the subject:

http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns.html