# How to pivot and concatenate data in a view?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I'm creating a view to serve as a report that displays row data from various tables as columns, in some cases involving concatenation.
My query works excellent when I use a temporary table, but it needs to be a view, and **I'm wrestling with converting the temporary table approach to subqueries**.

I've created a couple sample tables and data to simplify this question as much as possible.
Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] (
    [CarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Car] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] ASC))
 INSERT INTO [Car] VALUES
    (1, 'Honda')

CREATE TABLE [Part] (
    [PartId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PercentComplete] [decimal](3, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([PartId] ASC))
INSERT INTO [Part] VALUES
    (1, 'Engine', 0.5)
    ,(1, 'Transmission', 0.75)
    ,(1, 'Suspension', 0.3)
```

Here's the initial step:

```
SELECT
    c.CarId
    ,c.Name AS [CarName]
    ,p.Name AS [PartName]
    ,p.PercentComplete AS [PartPercentComplete]
INTO #Temp
FROM Car c
JOIN Part p
ON p.CarId = c.CarId
```

[image: Initial Setup]

Here's the grouped select which converts it to my report view:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CarName) AS [Car Name]

    ,STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [PartName] 
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE (CarId = t1.CarId) 
        FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,2,'') AS [Parts]

    ,MAX(CASE [PartCompleteAvg] WHEN 1.00 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Incomplete' END) AS [Part Status]
    ,MAX(CASE [PartId] WHEN [LatestPartId] THEN [PartName] ELSE NULL END) AS [Latest Part]
FROM (
    SELECT
        CarId
        ,AVG(PartPercentComplete) AS [PartCompleteAvg]
        ,MAX(PartId) AS [LatestPartId]
    FROM #Temp
    GROUP BY CarId
) t1
LEFT JOIN #Temp t2
ON t2.CarId = t1.CarId
GROUP BY t1.CarId
```

[image: Report]

It works fantastic except I have trouble converting it to a view because of the intermediate aggregate function `AVG(PartPercentComplete)`, and the concatenation trick with `STUFF`. My report requires several of each of these.

I know I can't nest `AVG()` within `MAX()` as that gives `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

(FYI I'm aware of `PIVOT` but it'd need to be over [multiple columns](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns.html), though I realize that's possible too, `CASE` seems easier and [I'm told faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3241524/879).)

My totally incorrect and poor attempt:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CarName) AS [Car Name]
    ,STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [PartName] 
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE (CarId = t1.CarId) 
        FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,2,'') AS [Parts]

    ,MAX(CASE [PartCompleteAvg] WHEN 1.00 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Incomplete' END) AS [Part Status]
FROM (
    SELECT
        CarId
        ,AVG(PartPercentComplete) AS [PartCompleteAvg]
    FROM (
        SELECT
            c.CarId
            ,c.Name AS [CarName]
            ,p.Name AS [PartName]
            ,p.PercentComplete AS [PartPercentComplete]
        FROM Car c
        JOIN Part p
        ON p.CarId = c.CarId
    ) t1
    GROUP BY CarId
) t1
LEFT JOIN #Temp t2
ON t2.CarId = t1.CarId
GROUP BY t1.CarId
```

Obviously `#Temp` is invalid in both locations. I'm not a SQL expert and I'm hoping there is a clean and relatively simple way to do this, maybe even avoiding the self-join.

**Edit**

I added in

```
MAX(PartId) AS [LatestPartId]
```

and

```
MAX(CASE [PartId] WHEN [LatestPartId] THEN [PartName] ELSE NULL END) AS [Latest Part]
```

as it's a better example of why I need an intermediate `GROUP BY`.

Comment: what is the final result that you are looking for?

Comment: The same as in my last image, except as a view. I have it working with a temporary table, but not as a view. I'm not sure how to do an intermediate group by with aggregate functions (as I do with my temporary table) in a view, nor do I know how to make the XML PATH concatenation trick work, which currently uses `FROM #Temp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard put me on the right track. Here's what I was looking for:

```
SELECT c.CarId
    ,c.Name AS [CarName]
    ,STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Name
        FROM Part p
        WHERE p.CarId = c.CarId
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS [Parts]
    ,CASE WHEN Progress = 1 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Incomplete' END AS [Part Status]
    ,[Latest Part]
FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT p.CarId
    ,SUM(PercentComplete)/COUNT(1) AS [Progress]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN PartId = LatestPartId THEN p.Name ELSE NULL END) AS [Latest Part]
    FROM Part p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT CarId
        ,MAX(PartId) AS [LatestPartId]
        FROM Part
        GROUP BY CarId
    ) latestPart
    ON latestPart.CarId = p.CarId
    GROUP BY p.CarId
) partInfo
ON partInfo.CarId = c.CarId
```

The key was to leave `GROUP BY` out of the main select (much preferred) and put my aggregation code in a series of JOINs using `GROUP BY`, nesting a join when necessary to compute some intermediate information.

I feel foolish as I hadn't thought of using `SELECT` within `JOIN`, my brain only wanted to think of using it within `FROM`. Now I can use pivoting and concatenation effectively!

### Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94583/15).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something in your requirements but does this not work for you (tested in SQL Server 2008 and created a view with it):

```
select max(c.name) CarName,
  STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + p.Name 
        from part p
        WHERE (p.CarId = c.CarId) 
        FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,2,'') AS [Parts],
   CASE AVG(p.PercentComplete) WHEN 1.00 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Incomplete' END AS [Part Status]
from car c
inner join part p
  on c.carid = p.carid
group by c.carid
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94583/12)

Comment: This works except in reality the `from car c1 inner join part p` section is far, far, longer, and I was hoping to avoid the code duplication, especially with several of these concatenations. Also it looks like I chose a bad example to demonstrate my need to do an intermediate group by step, since you took care of that quite nicely by just replacing the silly `MAX(AVG())` with `AVG()`, I will try and find a better example. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin feel free to expand on the sql fiddle that I posted and I post the link here, I will then take a look.

Comment: @blue Why do you feel the need to have car table twice?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated answer for the updated question.

```
;WITH A(CarID,CarName,PartName,IsComplete,RN)AS(
SELECT C.CarID, C.Name, P.Name, case when P.PercentComplete=1 then 1 else 0 end,
    rn=row_number() over (partition by C.CarID order by P.PartId)
From Car C
LEFT JOIN Part P on P.CarId = C.CarId
)
,B(CarID,CarName,PartNames,LastPartName,IsComplete,RN)AS(
select CarID,CarName,CAST(PartName as VARCHAR(max)),PartName,IsComplete,RN
from A
Where rn=1
union all
select A.CarID,A.CarName,B.PartNames+', '+A.PartName,A.PartName,Case when A.IsComplete=1 and B.IsComplete=1 then 1 else 0 end,A.RN
from B
join A on A.CarID=B.CarID and A.RN-1=B.RN
),C AS(
select *, RNc=Row_number() over (partition by CarID order by RN desc)
from B
)
select CarID,CarName,PartNames,LastPartName,IsComplete
from C
where RNc=1
```

Below this, the original answer.

---

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] (
    [CarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Car] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] ASC));
INSERT INTO [Car] VALUES (1, 'Honda'),
                         (2, 'Ford');

CREATE TABLE [Part] (
    [PartId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PercentComplete] [decimal](3, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([PartId] ASC));
INSERT INTO [Part] VALUES (1, 'Engine', 0.5),
                          (1, 'Transmission', 0.75),
                          (1, 'Suspension', 0.3),
                          (2, 'Engine', 1),
                          (2, 'Brake', 1.0);

   SELECT C.CarID,
          C.Name CarName,
          STUFF((
              SELECT ', ' + Name
               FROM Part
              WHERE CarId = C.CarId 
                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') Parts,
          CASE WHEN Progress = 1 then 'Complete' else 'Incomplete' END [Part Status]
     From Car C
LEFT JOIN (
   select CarId, SUM(PercentComplete)/Count(1) Progress
     From Part
 Group by CarId) P on P.CarID = C.CarId
```

```
CarID       CarName  Parts                               Part Status
----------- -------- ----------------------------------- -----------
1           Honda    Engine, Transmission, Suspension    Incomplete
2           Ford     Engine, Brake                       Complete
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to have to take a bit of time to wrap my head around everything and try it out, I will keep you updated. Meanwhile I updated my question, but it seems you may have already addressed what I was looking for.